# mailto launches the default mail client outlook but then current tab closes

Tags: javascript, anchor, mailto

I am using IE8.

```
var ClientContactsTable = document.getElementById("clientContacts");
var TableRow = ClientContactsTable.insertRow(1);
var Email=TableRow.insertCell(0);  
Email.setAttribute("className","CellValueWrap");
Email.innerHTML='My Name'==''?"&nbsp;":"<a class='ReportLink' target='_blank'    href='mailto:"+'me@gmail.com'+"'>"+"My Name"+"</a>";
        alert(Email.innerHTML);
```

When I am clicking on My Name - it launches Outlook, asks for permission (whether you want to launch the outlook client or not), once I do Allow it launches Outlook and then the tab which was running my app displays the address as me@gmail.com with blank content. then I have to do a back to go to my app page.
this is surely disappointing for my users.
This issue does not happen in Firefox. How to avoid it?
I tried both target='_blank' as well as _self but both causing same problem